# How to get word to pop-up on a list when I type one letter

Tags: html

```
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Property State</label>
                                                    <select name="Prorated.PropertyState " class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>
                                                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                                                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

For example, I've got a drop-down list to select a State. When I type in "C" for instance in the search area of the box, it doesn't bring back "California." Does the "option value" have to be changed to just a "C" ? If so, how would I do it for every State that has the same beginning letter, etc.?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `<select>` element is active, typing a letter that one of the options begins with will cause the first option that begins with that letter to become selected. Pressing the same letter again will cause the next option that begins with that letter to become selected and so on.

Run the snippet below (which uses your exact list) and activate the `<select>` (by either tabbing to it or clicking on it) and then press the "c" key. California will become selected. Press the "c" key again and Colorado will become selected. One more press and Connecticut becomes selected. Since that is the last `<option>` that starts with "c", another press of "c" will bring you back to California.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Property State</label>
                                                    <select name="Prorated.PropertyState " class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>
                                                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                                                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying for a type hint kinda thing, you could use datalist hinting

```
<datalist id="euroCountries">
  <option value="Austria">
  <option value="Belgium">
  <option value="Czech Republic">
  <option value="Denmark">
  <option value="Estonia">
  <option value="France">
  <option value="Germany">
</datalist>
```